# Dynamic replacing with perl

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I want to programmatically replace little placeholder with static content like the user name or working path.

Is there a possibility in bash that I can dynamically execute my perl replacement state like:

```
GROUPNAME="$(id -g -n $USER)"
perl -pi -e 's/\(PLACEHOLDER\)/' + "$GROUPNAME" + '/g' filepath/file
```

it would be the enormously good if I could also adapt this dynamical behaviour for the placeholder. But first things first. How do I concatenate these strings?

Comment: Not sure if that's a good match, because it's about variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `" + "` (spaces and plus). Bash does automatic concatenation for adjacent strings.

```
echo 'hi!'t"here"  # hi!there
```

Generating Perl code in this way is only safe because the output of `id -g -n $USER` won't contain `\`, `$`, `@` or `/`.

Comment: @ikegami: This use case is safe. Perhaps use `sed` for clarity.

Comment: It's coming from a trusted input (`id`).

Answer (score 2):

You were going for

```
GROUPNAME="$(id -g -n $USER)"
perl -i -pe's/\(PLACEHOLDER\)/'"$GROUPNAME"'/g' filepath/file
```

But there's no reason to generate Perl code. That is very error prone. Instead, use one of the following:

```
export GROUPNAME="$(id -g -n $USER)"
perl -i -pe's/\(PLACEHOLDER\)/$ENV{GROUPNAME}/g' filepath/file
```

or

```
GROUPNAME="$(id -g -n $USER)" perl -i -pe's/\(PLACEHOLDER\)/$ENV{GROUPNAME}/g' filepath/file
```